# Strange connection problems (no access to gmail, dropbox, bitbucket)

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

A few days ago I have started to have very strange problems with my wifi connection. The connection itself works fine with a strong signal and most websites working. The computer is running Ubuntu and I am connected to the internet via eduroam, in case this matters. I will just enumerate a number of things that have stopped working. Neither a restart nor deactivating the wifi and activating it again, nor changing browser have helped. All other devices connected to the same router work fine, only my desktop computer has this problem.

1. I cannot log into gmail.com, the site doesn't stop loading. My thunderbird still receives emails that are sent to my gmail adress but I can't send emails from my thunderbird. In fact also the google captcha on this site didn't work, so I had to post this question from a different computer.
2. Dropbox has stopped syncing and I cannot use the web interface, again the site doesn't load.
3. I had set up a number of git repositories with a repository on bitbucket as origin. When I type in git push or git pull I get

   > Connection closed by 2401:1d80:1010::150 port 22 fatal: Could not read
   >   from remote repository.

This worked perfectly fine just a few days ago (I also checked again that my ssh key is among the ssh keys enabled in my bitbucket account).

**Does anyone have any idea about what could be the problem?**

Comment: firewall maybe. check `sudo iptables -S` for any rules you might have set and forgot

Comment: Does it only happen on the Eduroam SSID or also on other SSID?

Comment: @sudorm-rf. I never changed anything in the firewall settings, the output is: -P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Comment: @CustomX: That's a very good point! I tried accessing the wifi via a hotspot from my phone and all problems are gone.

So what could be the problem with my eduroam connection?

Comment: @Michalis, It's possible that certain restrictions are enabled on the eduroam SSID. I've seen installations where outlook wouldn't download new email messages on the guest SSID. This was due to FW restrictions. I would contact the IT administrator to have a look at this. Should be a quick fix by adding it to the whitelist.

Comment: @CustomX: Thanks for your help. I contacted the support for my universities eduroam and they didn't find any restrictions on their side. Unfortunately they weren't able to help at all and I suspect they didn't take my problem very seriously, since I told them that all my other devices work just fine.